# Encoding Chinese characters to open JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, chinese-locale

I am unable to open a json file containing chinese and english characters. I have tried using-

```
with open('.//train//chess.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I have also tried other encodings (Latin-1, UTF-16, UTF-32, BIG5, GB) too but none of them work. Here is the json file as it shows in notepad++ -

{
"name": "tournament_test_2",
"start_date": "2020-01-20",
"end_date": "2020-02-09",
"games": {
"tour_1": [
{
"white": "吕亚光",
"black": "胡建静",
"date": "2020-01-20",
"id": "tournament_test_2_1"
},
{
"white": "崔军凯",
"black": "陈森",
"date": "2020-01-20",
"id": "tournament_test_2_2"
},
{
"white": "丁晨彤",
"black": "董海非",
"date": "2020-01-20",
"id": "tournament_test_2_3"
},
{
"white": "傅星菲",
"black": "张春",
"date": "2020-01-20",
"id": "tournament_test_2_4"
},
{
"white": "魏辟涛",
"black": "黄凯文",
"date": "2020-01-20",
"id": "tournament_test_2_5"
}
]
},
"tours": 1,
"time_control": "classic"
}

Here is the image of the data for a clearer picture -
[image]

I get the following error -

File "C:\Users\Asus-ROG\Desktop\Machine learning\hands-on\Chess\chess1.py", line 14, in 
d = json.load(f, encoding = "UTF-8")

File "C:\Users\Asus-ROG\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 293, in load
return loads(fp.read(),

File "C:\Users\Asus-ROG\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 180: character maps to

Comment: What error do you get? Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character decoding goes in the file `open()` method, rather than the json `load()` method:

```
import json
with open('chess.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read the json with :

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json('chess.json')
```